# A question regarding two surjective functions defined on the same domain, and a resulting logical equivalence.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, soft-question

Source : Reversat & Bigonnet, *Algèbre pour la licence* ( Undergraduate abstract algebra), 1997, p. $9$ .

THEOREM :

Let $s$ be a surjective function from $E$ to $F$ and $s'$ a surjective function defined from $E$ to $F'$.

The two following assertions are logically equivalent :

(1) $\forall x,y \space _{\in E} , s(x)=s(y) \implies s'(x)=s'(y)$

(2) There exists a unique function $u : F \rightarrow F'$ such that $s'= u\circ s $ , that is $ s'(x)= u(s(x))$.

PROOF [ I quote from beginning to end]  :

a) The proof of $(2) \implies (1) $ is obvious.

b) As to $(1) \implies (2)$.

- For all element $z= s(x)$ of $F$, let us set : $u(z)= s'(x)$.
- It is easy to check that $(1)$ implies that $u(z)$ only depends on $z$ ,  and therefore that function $u$ is well-defined.
- In virtue of the definition of function $u$ , we have :

$$\forall x\in E , s'(x)= u(s(x)) , $$

which implies that function $u$ is unique ( as desired).

---

I need this result in order to understand a theorem concerning group homomorphism , namely that , if $G$ is finite  $ |G| = |Ker\phi| \times |Im\phi|$ , with $\phi$ a homomorphism from group $G$ to a group $G'$, but the elliptic and cryptic proof above gets me stuck.

Can this proof be rephrased in a more reader friendly way?

I can't see how function $u$ could not depend on $z$ since it is *defined* as a function of $z$.

I can't see where hypothesis $(1)$ comes into play in the process that leads to (2) as consequent.

I definitely cannot see how $(2) \implies (1)$ is " obvious ".

Sorry for not being able to show my work. It ended at some useless sagittal representations of these functions, and yielded no result. "Stuck" as I said.

Comment: $|G|=|ker\phi)|\times|Im\phi|$ is always true because by Lagrange Theorem we have $|G|=|ker\phi|\times[G:ker\phi]$ and by the Homomorphism Theorem we have $G/ker\phi$ is isomorphic to $Im\phi$.

Comment: It should be "For all elements $z=s(x)$ of $F$" (not $f(x)$, there is no $f$), right? Also, they do not claim that $u$ does not depend on $z$; they claim it depends *only* on $z$, and not on the $x$ you chose from the preimage $s^{-1}(z)$ to define it -- note there can be many such $x$ with $s(x)=z$. And to  show $u(z)$ does not depend on what $x$ you chose, that's exactly where hypothesis (1) is needed.

Comment: For the obvious direction, well assuming (2), how can you write $s'(x)$ and $s'(y)$ alternatively?